# How to create a JSON object in MySql with a boolean value?

Tags: mysql, json, mysql-5.7

I would like my MySql query to return a JSON object that looks as follows:

```
{"name": "Piotr", "likesMysql": true}
```

This seems to be working fine when I do:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'name', 'Piotr',
    'likesMysql', TRUE
)
```

However when I try to derive the `likesMysql` from an `if` expression I get 
 `0` and `1` instead of `false` and `true` e.g.:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'name', 'Piotr',
    'likesMysql', if(4 MOD 2 = 0, TRUE, FALSE)
)
```

results in

```
{"name": "Piotr", "likesMysql": 1}
```

How do I use the `json_object` to construct a JSON object that has `true` or `false` as property value?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This seems to be [a bug in MySql](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79813).

You can workaround it though with `cast(true as json)` e.g.:

```
SELECT json_object(
    'name', 'Piotr',
    'likesMysql', if(4 MOD 2 = 0, cast(TRUE as json), cast(FALSE as json))
)
```

Comment: Having just come across this post, I respectfully have to comment that this is probably the most correct answer, both programmatically and for readability purposes.  Although the answer provided by Aniket may work under most conditions. IMHO.

Comment: Works with 5.7.34

Answer (score 5):

Simply go with following,

`SELECT json_object(
    'name', 'Piotr',
    'likesMysql', if(5 MOD 2 = 0, TRUE, FALSE) is true
)`

Hope you get desired result with this :)

Answer (score 2):

Aniket Bhansali's approach could be simplified as:

```sql
select json_object(
    'bool_true', (4 mod 2 = 0) is true,
    'bool_false', 0 is true) b;
```

which returns

```
{"bool_true": true, "bool_false": false}
```

Tested on mysql 8.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT json_object(
   'name', 'Piotr',
   'likesMysql', 4 MOD 2 != 0
)
```